# Get total value in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

While executing this query i always got the concession result as '0' only, totally i got 2 lakh customer data's, but for all customer's i got the concession value as '0'  only, what mistake i did in these query?

-- 4. Concession & Other pre-purchases

```
if (select count(*) FROM tbl_OrderFoodLog where OrderLog_ID in
    (select OrderLog_ID from  #MemberOrderLog where Member_MailId=@EmailId))>0

if (select count(*) from  #CustTrans where  OrderLog_IsFoodOrder='Y')>0
begin
    select  @Concession=(select SUM( FoodLog_Total) FROM tbl_OrderFoodLog where OrderLog_ID --in ( select OrderLog_ID from  #MemberOrderLog where Member_MailId=@EmailId))/
--(select -COUNT(*) from  #MemberOrderLog where Member_MailId=@EmailId) 
    select @FoodAmount=cast(SUM( FoodLog_Total) as float) FROM tbl_OrderFoodLog where OrderLog_ID in ( select OrderLog_ID from  #CustTrans where  OrderLog_IsFoodOrder='Y')
    select  @Concession=(@FoodAmount)/@Frequency
            end
        else
            begin
                select @Concession=0.00
            end
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't `COUNT(*)` if you just want to find out if rows exists - that's what `EXISTS()` is for. And try to calculate all you need in a single pass over a table, rather than multiple passes. Unfortunately, we don't have your data (in either your permanent tables nor your temp tables), so we're unable to diagnose further.

Comment: Thank you for replying Mr.Hims , actually my permanent table is Order Log and the Cinema Member, from both tables i just pull 'food order log='Y' customer's mail address, In that the customer did more than 3 transactions and in that 3 transactions, how many times customer booked Food. i took that count only... i think some what you can understand my scenario, Sorry suppose if i explained Badly.

Comment: kindly help me some one.... pls